# ES6 shorthand object key checking

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Curious to know if there's any part of ES6 that makes these kind of checks a little more concise:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps && nextProps.filterObj && nextProps.filterObj.area){
        // go ahead
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to read it or modify? For reading you may destructure it.

Comment: Short answer is no. I don't understand how destructuring will help. `var { filterObj: { area } } = nextProps;` will return the same error that `nextProps.filterObj.area` would.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, no existential operator has made it into ES6; it is [still discussed](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/existential-operator-null-propagation-operator) however.

You can use any of the [existing methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631001/1048572), of course, like

```
if ( ((nextProps||{}).filterObj||{}).area ) {
    // go ahead
}
```

Also you can try destructuring and default values:

```
function componentWillReceiveProps({filterObj: {area} = {}} = {}) {
    if (area) {
        // go ahead
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will swallow zeroes, empty strings and arrays. The correct way is to compare against `undefined` but it makes the code way too bulky.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov: I don't see why it would swallow zeroes and empty strings, you surely don't expect these anyway when you want to access another property on the value? If you mean for the `.area`, you surely can append a `!== undefined` comparison. And no, it certainly won't swallow arrays.

Comment: For example, you want `3` to be a default value, but `0` is also a legit value. If you do `value||3`, it will be impossible to pass a zero.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov: the only default value you use here is `{}` - when accessing properties, we only consider objects to be legit values.